# Directly solving non-square subproblem of linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a large sparse linear system

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    A & B\\
    C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    f \\
    g
\end{pmatrix}$$

which is non-symmetric, but positive definite and invertible. It has no further features to use for fast solving. $A$ and $D$ are square matrices, all matrices are sparse, $B$ and $C$ are very sparse.
I want to solve the non-symmetric subsystem $Ax=f$, but also get the changes for $B$. After the solving the system should look like

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    E & B'\\
    C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    f' \\
    g
\end{pmatrix}$$

with $E$ the identity matrix, modified $B$ and $f$ and the solution in $x$. It is a block Gauß solve.

How to achieve this with Matlab? Or with C++ and SuperLU or UMFPack?

Comment: So you want to write a function to do this?  You can implement a Gauss Seidel solver in MATLAB in very few lines of code.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method

Comment: @Jed: Kind of. But I don't want to write my own Gauß-Seidel, but to use the advanced algorithms from UMFPack or SuperLU

Comment: @Jed Why the Gauss-Seidel method? First, OP asks for a direct solution method and, second, Gauss-Seidel may converge very slowly if at all.

Comment: Is there something wrong with MATLAB's backslash operator on this system?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Backslash works for the whole, but it is too slow. $A$ is a weird matrix. Once $A$ is solved, I can solve the complete system with an iterative method. But I cannot apply to only $A$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Gauss Seidel because he said "block Gauss solve" and Gauss Seidel is a popular method.